# Error al inicializar constructores en Java

Tags: java, constructor

Estoy intentando hacer un programa para gestionar los productos de un almacén. Estoy teniendo un fallo al usar la clase Principal y la clase Productos al mostrar el constructor.

Clase principal:

```
package gestiondealmacen;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Principal {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        /*LISTA DE COSAS A INCLUIR EN ESTA PRÁCTICA
          - (Terminarla lo primero)
          - Encapsulamiento
          - Implements y extends
          - Polimorfismo
          - Abstracción (usar abstract. También static)
          - Sobrecarga de métodos y constructores
          - Inyección de dependencias
          - Comentarios*/

       Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
       boolean salir = false;
       int opcion;

       while(!salir){
           System.out.println("\n---MENÚ PRINCIPAL---");
           System.out.println("1. Gestionar productos");
           System.out.println("2. Gestionar el almacen");
           System.out.println("3. Gestionar clientes");
           System.out.println("4. Gestionar albaranes");
           System.out.println("5. Gestionar facturas");
           System.out.println("6. Operaciones sobre listados");
           System.out.println("7. SALIR\n");

           System.out.print("Escoge la opción deseada: ");
           opcion = sc.nextInt();

           //Ahora realizamos la opción que haya escogido
           // el usuario
           switch(opcion){
               case 1:
                   gestionarProductos();
                   break;

               case 2:
                   break;

               case 3:
                   break;

               case 4:
                   break;

               case 5:
                   break;

               case 6:
                   operacionesSobreListados();
                   break;

               case 7:
                   salir = true;
                   System.out.println("Gracias. Vuelva pronto\n");
                   break;
               default: //Capturar InputMismatchException
                   System.out.println("ERROR! Opción inválida\n");
           }
       }
    }

    public static void gestionarProductos(){
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        boolean volver = false;
        int opcion;

        while(!volver){
            System.out.println("\n---GESTIÓN DE PRODUCTOS---");
            System.out.println("1. Crear producto");
            System.out.println("2. Eliminar producto");
            System.out.println("3. Obtener un listado de los productos");
            System.out.println("4. VOLVER\n");
            System.out.print("Escoge la opción deseada: ");
            opcion = sc.nextInt();

            switch(opcion){
                case 1:
                    String referencia, fechaCaducidad;
                    int stock, ancho, alto;
                    double precioCompra, precioVenta, descuento;
                    int iProductos;

                    System.out.print("\nIntroduce la referencia del producto: ");
                    referencia = sc.next();
                    System.out.print("Introduce la fecha de caducidad del"
                    + " producto (dd/mm/aa): "); /*Capturar error fecha anterior
                    a la actual. Capturar fromato fecha*/
                    fechaCaducidad = sc.next();
                    System.out.print("Introduce el número de unidades de"
                            + " tu producto (stock): ");
                    stock = sc.nextInt();
                    System.out.print("Dimensiones del producto. Introduce el"
                            + " ancho (cm): ");
                    ancho = sc.nextInt();
                    System.out.print("Introduce el alto (cm): ");
                    alto = sc.nextInt();
                    System.out.print("Introduce el precio de compra (€): "); //Limitar a dos decimales
                    precioCompra = sc.nextDouble();
                    precioVenta = precioCompra * 1.5;
                    System.out.print("El precio de venta será de " + precioVenta
                            + "€\n");
                    System.out.print("Introduce el descuento aplicable en"
                            + " factura (un porcentaje): "); //Hacer que sólo sea entre 0 y 99
                    descuento = sc.nextDouble();

                    Productos pr = new Productos(referencia, stock, ancho, alto,
                    precioCompra, precioVenta, descuento, fechaCaducidad);

                    System.out.print("\nEl producto se ha creado. Compruébalo"
                            + " usando la opción 3 de este menú\n");
                    break;

                case 2:
                    break;

                case 3:
                    for(iProductos=0; iProductos<5; iProductos++){
                        System.out.println("Referencia: " + pr.getReferencia());
                        System.out.println("Stock: " + pr.getStock());
                        System.out.println("Ancho: " + pr.getAncho());
                        System.out.println("Alto: " + pr.getAlto());
                        System.out.println("Precio de compra: " + pr.getPrecioCompra());
                        System.out.println("Precio de venta: " + pr.getPrecioVenta());
                        System.out.println("Descuento: " + pr.getDescuento());
                        System.out.println("Fecha de caducidad: " + pr.getFechaCaducidad());    
                    }

                    if(iProductos==0){
                        System.out.println("No hay ningún producto en el almacén."
                    + "Puedes añadir productos usando la opción 1 de este menú\n");
                    }
                    break;

                case 4:
                    volver = true;
                    break;
                default: //Capturar InputMismatchException
                    System.out.println("ERROR! Opción inválida\n");
            }
       }
    }

    public static void operacionesSobreListados(){
    //Puede que se metan dentro de las otras opciones del menú principal
        int opcion;
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        boolean volver = false;


        while (!volver){
            System.out.println("\n---MENÚ DE LISTADOS---");
            System.out.println("1. Obtener un listado de los productos");
            System.out.println("2. Obtener un listado de Albaranes");
            System.out.println("3. Obtener un listado de productos buscados a"
                    + " partir de un precio de venta mayor a una cantidad");
            System.out.println("4. Obtener un listado de albaranes generados en"
                    + "una fecha concreta");
            System.out.println("5. Obtener la suma total económica de productos"
                    + " vendidos");
            System.out.println("6. Obtener un listado de las facturas pendientes"
                                                                + "de cobro");
            System.out.println("7. Obtener un listado detallado de las facturas"
                    + "de un cliente");
            System.out.println("8. Saber el stock de un producto concreto");
            System.out.println("9. VOLVER");

            System.out.print("Escoge la opcion deseada: ");
            opcion = sc.nextInt();
            //Nelson 1-4
            switch(opcion){
               case 1:
                   break;

               case 2:
                   break;

               case 3:
                   break;

               case 4:
                   break;

               case 5:
                   break;

               case 6:                   
                   break;

               case 7:                   
                   break;

               case 8:                   
                   break;

               case 9:
                   volver = true;
                   break;
               default: //Capturar InputMismatchException
                   System.out.println("ERROR! Opción inválida\n");
            }
        } 
    }
}
```

Clase productos:

```
package gestiondealmacen;
import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.GregorianCalendar;

public class Productos {
    private String referencia;
    private int stock;
    private int ancho;
    private int alto;
    private double precioCompra;
    private double precioVenta;
    private double descuento; //CUANTO DESCUENTO????
    private String fechaCaducidad;

    public Productos(String vReferencia, int vStock, int vAncho, int vAlto,
    double vPrecioCompra, double vPrecioVenta, double vDescuento,
    String vfechaCaducidad){
        referencia = vReferencia;
        stock = vStock;
        ancho = vAncho;
        alto = vAlto;
        precioCompra = vPrecioCompra;
        precioVenta = vPrecioVenta;
        descuento = vDescuento;
        fechaCaducidad = vfechaCaducidad;
    }

    public String getReferencia() {
        return referencia;
    }

    public void setReferencia(String referencia) {
        this.referencia = referencia;
    }

    public int getStock() {
        return stock;
    }

    public void setStock(int stock) {
        this.stock = stock;
    }

    public int getAncho() {
        return ancho;
    }

    public void setAncho(int ancho) {
        this.ancho = ancho;
    }

    public int getAlto() {
        return alto;
    }

    public void setAlto(int alto) {
        this.alto = alto;
    }

    public double getPrecioCompra() {
        return precioCompra;
    }

    public void setPrecioCompra(double precioCompra) {
        //Utilizaremos euros como moneda, los cuales solo admiten 2 decimales
        precioCompra = Math.round(precioCompra * 100.0) / 100.0;
        this.precioCompra = precioCompra;
    }

    public double getPrecioVenta() {
        return precioVenta;
    }

    public void setPrecioVenta(double precioVenta) {
        //El precio de venta será un 50% más que el precio de compra
        //precioVenta = this.precioCompra * 1.5;

        precioVenta = Math.round(precioVenta * 100.0) / 100.0;
        this.precioVenta = precioVenta;
    }

    public double getDescuento() {
        return descuento;
    }

    public void setDescuento(double descuento) {
        this.descuento = descuento;
    }

    public String getFechaCaducidad() {
        return fechaCaducidad;
    }

    public void setFechaCaducidad (String fechaCaducidad){
        GregorianCalendar fCaducidad = new GregorianCalendar();

        //La fecha de caducidad será 30 días después de su producción
        fCaducidad.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, 30);
        fechaCaducidad = (fCaducidad.get(Calendar.YEAR)) + "/" +
        (fCaducidad.get(Calendar.MONTH) + "/" + fCaducidad.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH));

        this.fechaCaducidad = fechaCaducidad;
    }
}
```

En el case 3 del menú de productos de la clase Principal me sale el siguiente error cada vez que llamo a uno de los getters de la clase Productos: `variable pr might not have been initializated`. En el case 1 ya le pongo valores al crear un producto. Ya he probado a intentar poner cadenas vacías a los string o 0s a los int y double para inicializar los valores del constructor (en ambas clases), pero me sigue dando el error. ¿Cómo debo inicializar el constructor para que no me de errores sin perder el producto que he guardado en el case 1 de la gestión de productos de la clase principal?

PD: Soy consciente de que, tal como lo tengo, solo puedo crear un producto y los demás se sobreescriben. No me importa, ya que lo corregiré por mi cuenta después de solucionar esta pregunta.

Comment: El compilador está en lo cierto. Entiendo que tu idea es tener una lista de productos, sin embargo, al "crear" un producto, declaras una variable local a la que asignas una nueva instancia de producto, sin guardar una referencia a dicha instancia. Al crear un nuevo producto, perderás la referencia al producto anteriormente creado. Luego, intentas hacer un ciclo para _imprimir_ los detalles del producto, donde intentas re-utilizar la variable `pr`, que puede o no contener una referencia a un producto. Es lo que el compilador te está alertando, que la variable `pr` podría no tener una ref válida

Comment: Si quieres tener varios productos, utiliza un arreglo o una lista para almacenarlos.  No utilices variables con una visibilidad muy amplia, pues da lugar a confusiones. Cuando sea necesario, declara variables locales con una visibilidad reducida y utilízalas solo dentro del mismo bloque de código donde las has declarado.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El error : `variable pr might not have been initializated` indica que la variable está vacía (no confundir con nula), eso significa que tampoco servirán los métodos de esta.

Como el objeto de tipo `Producto` se ha creado pero no inicializado o pasado un valor, este siempre dejará el mismo error, deberías de hacer el `Productos pr = new Productos(..)` fuera del `swith`, pero ya perdería el sentido, para evitar ello podrías realizar lo siguiente.

**Veo que el error aparece dentro del `case 3` del primer `switch` y según el menú la salida esperada al seleccionar esa opción, debería de ser un listado de los productos.**

En primer lugar, para guardar las instancias de una clase es recomendable, crear un `ArrayList`, del tipo de clase, la cual almacena objetos de tipo `Producto` (recomiendo generar una clase `ControladorProductos`, donde vaya todas las acciones del `crud`):

He creado la clase `ControladorProducto` con lo siguiente en su interior.

```java
    //ArrayList donde se almacenarán todos las instancias de productos
    private static ArrayList<Productos> productosAl = new ArrayList<>();

    //devuelve todos los productos que se encuentran en el array
    public static ArrayList<Productos> devuelveProductos(){
        return productosAl; //revuelve el array completo
    }

    //busca un producto por su referencia, utilizando el arraylist
    public static Productos buscaProducto(String referencia){
        Productos prod= null; //objeto iniciado null
        for(int i = 0; i < productosAl.size(); i++){ //recorre array list
            if (referencia.equals(productosAl.get(i).getReferencia())){
                prod = productosAl.get(i);//si lo encuentra toma el objeto
            }
        }
        return prod; //retorna null y no encuentra el producto
    }

    //agrega un producto devuelve un int dependiendo de las posibles opciones
    //1 = agregó correctamente
    //0 = error al agregar
    //-1 = producto que ya existe, no es posible agregar otra vez
    public static int agregarProducto(Productos prod){
        int estado = 0;
        if(buscaProducto(prod.getReferencia())==null){
            productosAl.add(prod);
            estado = 1;//no encontrado se agrega al array
        }else{
            estado = -1; //encontrado, no es posible agregar
        }
        return estado;
    }
```

Tengo 3 métodos hasta ahora, buscar un producto por su `referencia` el cual es usado para agregar productos al `ArrayList` de tipo `Productos`, ya que si al buscar encuentra un `Producto` con la misma `referencia`, no agregará el producto al `ArrayList` `productosal`.

Adicional a esos dos tengo un método que devuelve el array completo de productos.

---

Además dentro del case 3, he modificado lo siguiente:

```java
case 3:

     for(iProductos=0; iProductos<ControladorProducto.devuelveProductos().size(); iProductos++){
         //pr toma el objeto encontrado en el índice del array
         Productos pr = ControladorProducto.devuelveProductos().get(iProductos);
         System.out.println("Referencia: " + pr.getReferencia());
         System.out.println("Stock: " + pr.getStock());
         System.out.println("Ancho: " + pr.getAncho());
         System.out.println("Alto: " + pr.getAlto());
         System.out.println("Precio de compra: " + pr.getPrecioCompra());
         System.out.println("Precio de venta: " + pr.getPrecioVenta());
         System.out.println("Descuento: " + pr.getDescuento());
         System.out.println("Fecha de caducidad: " + pr.getFechaCaducidad());    
     }

     if(iProductos==0){
         System.out.println("No hay ningún producto en el almacén."
                    + "Puedes añadir productos usando la opción 1 de este menú\n");
     }
     break;
```

Como `ControladorProducto.devuelveProductos()` devuelve el array completo, y este puede tener un tamaño variable, he utilizado el método `size()`, que devuelve el tamaño del `ArrayList`, dado a esto el `for` recorre nada más que el tamaño justo.

---

También he utilizado el método que tengo para crear un producto en la clase `ControladorProducto`:

```
int logrado = ControladorProducto.agregarProducto( new Productos(referencia, stock, ancho, alto,
precioCompra, precioVenta, descuento, fechaCaducidad));

if(logrado==1){
     System.out.print("\nEl producto se ha creado. Compruébalo"
                          + " usando la opción 3 de este menú\n");
}
```

Por último como `agregarProducto()` devuelve un int, le paso ese resultado a la variable logrado, si logrado es 1, imprime el mensaje.

Answer (score 0):

Para acceder a los métodos de una instancia en Java debes crearla u obtenerla previamente.

En el bucle `for` debes añadir una llamada para "recuperar" el producto a mostrar.

```
for(iProductos=0; iProductos<5; iProductos++){
    // Debes implementar un método para obtener el producto a partir del ID
    pr = getProductoById(iProductos);
    System.out.println("Referencia: " + pr.getReferencia());
    System.out.println("Stock: " + pr.getStock());
    System.out.println("Ancho: " + pr.getAncho());
    System.out.println("Alto: " + pr.getAlto());
    System.out.println("Precio de compra: " + pr.getPrecioCompra());
    System.out.println("Precio de venta: " + pr.getPrecioVenta());
    System.out.println("Descuento: " + pr.getDescuento());
    System.out.println("Fecha de caducidad: " + pr.getFechaCaducidad());    
}
```